# Combining 2 SQL Queries From A Single Table and Being Able to Update it

Tags: sql

I got a db with 23 Fields in them.  Of the 23 I need to manipulate 8 of them which we will call F1, F2, F3 ... F8(UserName).

For each of the 8 fields, a user can limit information between them.  For example the user only wants to see information from F1 starting with letter A to J plus they can specify any sort order between the 8 fields meaning they want it sorted first by F8 then by F6 then by F2 etc.  This is what it looks like:

```
  A     F2Upper  F3Upper ... F8Upper
  J     F2Lower  F3Lower ... F8Lower
Order1  Order2   Order3  ... Order8
  F1       F2       F3         F8(UserName)
```

I already have a working SQL query for all this.  Recently the company added a new criteria.  On top of all that data delimiting, they also want all information shown that have '~Prio' in F4 coupled with the F8(Username) irregardless of whatever are inside the delimiters.

So I made a UNION statement for the 2 queries and it worked but it cannot be updated. I need the data to be updateable.  What is the best way to go about it?  So my query goes like this:

```
Select *
  From tblTest
 WHERE F4 Like '~Prio'
   AND (F8 = CurrentUser or F8 = Location)
UNION
Select *
  From tblTest
 WHERE (F1 >= F1Upper AND F1 <= F1Lower)
   AND (F2 >= F2Upper AND F2 <= F2Lower)..
 .
   AND (F8 >= F8Upper AND F8 <= F8Lower)
 ORDER By Order1, Order2,
          Order3 .. .
          Order8
```

Comment: What does the query used to display the data have to do with updating it?

Comment: @Barmar he just wanted to know how to get the same result without using union (so that he could use it in an update query)

Comment: I thought he might be talking about displaying the results in a grid and allowing the users to update selected records. In that case, the query used to generate the grid is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to group the criteria like this:

```
Select *
  From tblTest
 WHERE ((F1 >= F1Upper AND F1 <= F1Lower) AND
       (F2 >= F2Upper AND F2 <= F2Lower)..
        . AND (F8 >= F8Upper AND F8 <= F8Lower))
    or (F4 Like '~Prio' AND (F8 = CurrentUser or F8 = Location))
 ORDER By Order1, Order2,
 Order 3 .. .
 Order 8
```